# Excel Automation in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel

I am aware that this approach is not recommended and should be avoid at all cost. So please do not answer me of using a third party library or any thing related

First the system creates a file and writes html inside it to display data. The system is fooling MS Excel by naming it with a .xls extension even though what it contains is html.

Aim:
   I need to convert it to REAL XLS file. So i want to open it using COM and save it as xls.

Problem:
   Now what happens is that it gives throws an exception that i don't know where it from. On the Development environment it is working pretty fine. but whenever we transfer it to the server. The problem occurs. I cannot debug on the server ( I know I must not) but i think i have no other choice. Here is the exception thrown

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [COMException (0x800a03ec): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC.]
>
> PLDTGlobal.Remco.ExcelCOM.SaveFileAsXLS(String filePath, String fileName, String path)
>
> PLDTGlobal.Remco.OtherFulfilments.BatchFiles.__InsertBDO.SaveRecord()
>
> PLDTGlobal.Remco.OtherFulfilments.BatchFiles.__InsertBDO.cmdSave_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +108
>
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +57
>
> System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +18
>
> System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +33
>
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain() +1292
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:1.1.4322.2032; ASP.NET Version:1.1.4322.2032.

Environment Details:

DEV

Windows XP Professional SP3,
Visual Studio 2003,
.NET 1.1,
MS EXCEL 11.0 Object Library

Server

Windows Server 2008 R2 (x64)

Here is an excerpt of the code:

```
public ExcelCOM()
{
    try
    {
        excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        excelApp.Visible = true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorLogger logger = new ErrorLogger();
        logger.WriteErrorLog(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        throw ex;
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// Opens the xml file using Excel COM library and converts it to .xls(1997-2003) format
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filePath">complete file path from target file</param>
/// <param name="fileName">filename of the target</param>
/// <param name="path">new path where to save the .xls</param>
public void SaveFileAsXLS(string filePath, string fileName, string path)
{
    object missingParam = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    string fileToCreate = path + fileName.Substring(0, fileName.Length - 4);        

    try
    {           
        if(!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
        excelApp.Visible = false;
        Excel.Workbook workBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath,  0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
        Excel.Worksheet workSheet1 = (Excel.Worksheet) workBook.Sheets.get_Item(1);
        workSheet1.Name = "Sheet1";
        workSheet1.SaveAs(fileToCreate, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel9795, missingParam, missingParam, false, missingParam, missingParam, missingParam, missingParam, missingParam);
        workBook.Close(missingParam, missingParam, missingParam);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workSheet1);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workBook);

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorLogger logger = new ErrorLogger();
        logger.WriteErrorLog(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        throw ex;
    }       
    finally
    {   
        excelApp.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);
    }
}
```

I have tried giving launch permission to NETWORK SERVICE account in dcomcnfg.

Any idea about the problem and how to solve it is much appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure from looking at the code, but there are tons of memory leaks here. `GC.Collect();` etc... should be in the `finally`.

Comment: If the file contains html, how do you expect it to look like in xls?

Comment: Did you search for error code `0x800A03EC`?

Comment: @T.S. Excel sometimes able to pull table data from HTML. I'm not sure why OP pick 2 questionable things (read HTML as XLS and run Excel on server) to try at the same time - one at a time would be easier (running Excel on server not going to be supported magically, but one bad idea at a time is may be simple to diagnose).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov it would be more efficient to fill Excel file using Microsoft ACE OleDb. Would probably do same thing in a "server safe" way

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Searching for error `0x800A03EC` is like pointing into the sky. Anything that is unhanded by Microsoft is probably shows this

Comment: excel will be able to display data if in <table> tag, not very sure about it but its working. and to answer why I look so dumb on doing this if there are easier way. Its because this system is very old and have no time to check all codes. I am trying to add a functionality and at the same time avoid modifying the already working system.

Comment: Also take note of the framework version I am using and the VS Studio. its way too old but got no choice :(.

Comment: @KiX Ortillan: Doesn't help much, but I do feel sorry for you. :D

Comment: May be there's something wrong with the arguments that are passing, when you try to save the Excel file. [Refer this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3ecbc477-a5d9-4033-887b-3e7dbaf2b7cb/saving-an-excel-file-exception-from-hresult-0x800a03ec?forum=vsto)

Comment: As you mentioned the code does work on DEV machine but not production one, have you checked the office versions between your DEV and Production boxes? as well as machine settings - what's the mode do you use the office - run as service?

Comment: @Rex Both the dev and prod have MS Excel 2003 installed.

Comment: then i would say you have to do a couple of testing: first log the file name to be created in production (guess it might be different from Dev one) and RDP (if possible) into the production machine, manually save a file with same name and path, if same error occurs, then mostlikely there is something wrong with account access permission, for example, does the ASPNET has written access to the designated folder? another possible problem is the file name - for excel, it should have no '[]' exist, apart from normal invalid chars.

Comment: @Rex Thanks for those advice. I'll look onto it. These are the things I'm hoping someone would answer. I don't need specifics. Just some clues would surely help.

Comment: welcome. hope you could resolve the problem by now, i knew how hard it was to work with excel interop on asp.net server...

Comment: If expence is allowed for the completion of this, it might be worth investigating a 3rd party library like syncfusion?  Not sure if they support 1.1 (I did have a quick skim, nothing obvious though). You might be able to negotiate a discount for an older version...  Would also remove need for Excel licence on your server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will work. I do run a development environment on my server, for just these kinds of issues.  I wrote code to automate Excel in Visual Studio 2013, code works great.  When I put the code into IIS 7 (2012 server), the code stops working.  From my research, this is by design by Microsoft because they do not want you doing this.  I had to change a whole lot of permissions to get it to even partially work. In the end, I cannot get Excel to display and officially, Microsoft says that Excel will throw errors because this is not supported.